# Yii2 - Generate common error in validation (not related with particular attribute)

Tags: validation, activerecord, yii2

I would like to apply a validator for ActiveRecord but not for particular field, I mean, I would like see the validator in the error summary of the form but not associated to a particular field.

Comment: can you be more specific and give an example? I'm guessing what you're looking for is overriding the validation method but hard to say without more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing a custom validation, you need to use `addError` method of `yii\base\Model` (if you write it in model) or `yii\validators\Validator` (if you write separate validator).

Both methods require `$attribute` parameter (attribute name) to be passed, and as you can see from the sources, you can't leave it blank:

`addError` of `yii\base\Model`:

```
/**
 * Adds a new error to the specified attribute.
 * @param string $attribute attribute name
 * @param string $error new error message
 */
public function addError($attribute, $error = '')
{
    $this->_errors[$attribute][] = $error;
}
```

`addError` of `yii\validators\Validator`:

```
/**
 * Adds an error about the specified attribute to the model object.
 * This is a helper method that performs message selection and internationalization.
 * @param \yii\base\Model $model the data model being validated
 * @param string $attribute the attribute being validated
 * @param string $message the error message
 * @param array $params values for the placeholders in the error message
 */
public function addError($model, $attribute, $message, $params = [])
{
    $params['attribute'] = $model->getAttributeLabel($attribute);
    if (!isset($params['value'])) {
        $value = $model->$attribute;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $params['value'] = 'array()';
        } elseif (is_object($value) && !method_exists($value, '__toString')) {
            $params['value'] = '(object)';
        } else {
            $params['value'] = $value;
        }
    }
    $model->addError($attribute, Yii::$app->getI18n()->format($message, $params, Yii::$app->language));
}
```

Possible options:

**1)** Select the most important relevant field and add error to it.

**2)** Select multiple important relevant fields and add the same error message to them (you can store and pass message in separate variable before passing to keep code DRY).

**3)** You can use not existing attribute name for adding error, let's say `all`, because attribute existence is not checked at that point.

```
class YourForm extends \yii\base\Model
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [                
            ['name', 'yourCustomValidationMethod'],
        ];
    }        

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function yourCustomValidationMethod()
    {
        // Perform your custom validation here regardless of "name" attribute value and add error when needed
        if (...) {
            $this->addError('all', 'Your error message');
        }            
    }
}
```

Note that you still need to attach validator to existing attribute(s) (otherwise exception will be thrown). Use the most relevant attribute.

As a result, you will see error only in error summary. You can display error summary in form like that:

```
<?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>
```

But in most cases there are always one or multiple attributes related with error so I recommend to use option **1** or **2**. Option **3** is kind of hack but I think still pretty elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. My objective is validate streets and cities, and I want to validate that one street is not exist at the same city, for that I search on database by street and city, if this record exists I want to return: "The street exists in this city". I didn't want associate the error to address name for example because this, could be confused for user.

Comment: @Fdezdam Better to mention such details initially when writing a question. If answer solved your problem, please accept it. See this [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.